# Confused with voltage divider

Tags: voltage, voltage-divider, physics

I'm confused with voltage divider..For the voltage going into Base, do I use the formula A or B to calculate? After searching some infos on google, I assume A is the right formula?

What's confusing me is that in my book, it says Voltage XY = 40/50, and Voltage YZ = 10/50.

[image]

Comment: Both are not really correct, because you did not take into account the DC input resistance of the BJT in parallel to the 10k part (or are you allowed no neglect the dc bias current IB?)

Comment: Yeah that book needs throwing away if they are telling you that.

Comment: Only a current flows **into** the base of the BJT, not a voltage! A voltage is always measured **between** two nodes, e.g., the base and the emitter. Ok, you can define Y and B as different nodes, but then the voltage between them would be zero because they are connected by a wire with zero resistance. Please fix your question.

Answer (score 2):

All voltages are relative to something; if you're not specifying, it's usually ground, which is 'Z' in this schematic.

Thus, 'voltage XY' is the voltage across the 40 kiloohm resistor, which is the difference between the positive supply voltage and the base. 'voltage YZ' is the voltage across the 10 kiloohm resistor, which is the difference between the ground and the base.

Since you're usually talking about voltage relative to ground, the latter is what you want if you just want to know 'the voltage on the base'.

Comment: Except that it wont be of course. The transistor base will start conducting, limiting the voltage at Y (with respect to Z) to about 0.7V

Comment: @Icy Certainly. I was only trying to answer the question about the voltage divider equation. Note I just explained what each voltage means, not what value it will have.

Answer (score 1):

What is the name of this book ? 
If we remove transistor from the circuit the voltage at point Y (the voltage difference between point Y and Z) is equal to : $$ V_Y = V_X *\frac{10k\Omega}{40k\Omega + 10k\Omega}= V_X\frac{10}{50} $$ 
But if you connect the BJT back into the circuit the voltage at **Vy** will now be equal to **Vbe**.

Comment: The voltage **Vyz** would have been an upper limit of around 0.7 V if the BJT is connected. But, it could also be lower if, e.g., **Vx** is just 1V. In this case the BJT would not (really) conduct.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you asked for the voltage \$V_{YZ}\$ in the DC steady state.

The voltage \$V_{YZ}\$ not only depends on the resistor values and the voltage \$V_{XZ}\$, but also on the current \$I_B\$ flowing into the transistor base. That is because the BJT is connected as a load to the voltage divider.

Applying Kirchoff's current law at node Y gives $$I_1 = I_B + I_2$$ where

- \$I_1\$ is the current through the upper resistor \$R_1 = 40k\Omega\$ flowing from X to Y, and
- \$I_2\$ is the current through the lower resistor \$R_2=10k\Omega\$ flowing from Y to Z.

If you replace the currents through the resistors by the voltages across them (same direction!) using Ohm's law and Kirchoff's voltage law, you get:

$$\frac{V_{XZ}-V_{YZ}}{R_1} = I_B + \frac{V_{YZ}}{R_2}$$

Now, just transpose the equation to \$V_{YZ}\$.

EDIT: There is also a dependency between the base current \$I_B\$ and the base-emitter voltage \$V_{BE}=V_{YZ}\$ of the BJT. It is analog to the [diode equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode#Shockley_diode_equation). But this depends on transistor parameters. For collector currents in the milli ampere range, \$V_{BE}\$ will be in the range 0.6 ... 0.7 volts.